# When installing Oracle, what's the quickest way to check rpm packages and install what is  missing?

Tags: oracle, installation

When installing Oracle, there is a step which is to install all necessary packages. I use the following command to test whether a package is installed and install them if they are missing:

```
rpm -qa | grep binutils
```

I know I can verify all packages in this way, but I want to know whether there is a better and quicker way to do this task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Howard Roger's [gladstone](http://diznix.com/2011/03/21/gladstone/) shell script. His scripts have always done a great job for me in performing all the necessary pre-installation tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely - just install the [Oracle Validated RPM](http://blogs.oracle.com/AlejandroVargas/entry/how_to_install_the_oracle-vali) and hey presto, everything you need is installed in a single command. Works with OEL and Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle Linux Operating System:

```
yum install oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall -y
```

It installs required packages for oracle database 12c R1